# Platform Event Subscription not working for some users!

Tags: lightning-aura-components, platform-event

I have a generic platform event for Record updates. (`RecordChange__e`)

I am firing that event in apex and subscribing it in an aura component in LEX.

It's working fine for me and other System Admins. But not working for other Users (like Call Center Agents who use service console, where **empAPI** is housed).

Are there any obvious permissions I am missing?

Comment: How are other users accessing the component? On desktop, mobile?

Comment: are those user's profile API enabled?

Comment: Yes! That Profile is API enabled.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is in-fact a permission issue. 
Since, Platform events are also sObjects. I needed to give read permission to that sObject in the permission set for that profile.

for debugging, I added an error callback to empApi

```
const empApi = cmp.find("empApi");
empApi.onError($A.getCallback(error => {
    console.error('EMP API error: ', JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(error)));
}));
```

Then, I got this error..

```
{
    channel: "/meta/subscribe"
    clientId: "3ka14r4jh9wtgreco75x81z39t2j"
    error: "403:denied_by_security_policy:create_denied"
    id: "579"
    subscription: "/event/RecordUpdate__e"
    successful: false
}
```

Thanks to @jayant-das's answer in this [forum post](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=9060G000000MPEbQAO). I was able to figure it out.